Extra Neutral slots needed
I have 6 Empty neutral slots left on my bus bar that are hidden underneath the main inlet wires and inaccessible. I need those spots to finish adding the additional breakers allowed in my panel.
How can I add an additional neutral bar for those 6 spots?
Homn24m 125 series 2 breaker box

Can you add a picture of what you mean by "hidden by the main inlet wires"?

Do you currently have any ground wires on the neutral bar? That is legitimate in a main panel but adding a ground bar and moving ground wires to free up neutral bar spaces may be easy.

What on Earth is a Homn24m??

Model number as stated appears to be a massive typo, even if I start with guessing SquareD HOMline nothing even comes close to matching that number. Please [edit] to correct, better yet, provide clear pictures including the text on the labeling.

Full neutral bar on a Main panel (without a ground bar, which is the easy solution) generally requires using the "multiple grounds in a neutral hole" option that is generally allowed by labeling (2 or 3 grounds per hole, torqued as specified on the panel's label for that number/size of wires.) Neutrals are always and only one per hole, unless mistakes were made.

Can you post photos of the inside of your panel please?

1 neutral wire per lug is both a UL rule and (now) a NEC rule, since everyone ignored the UL rule.
Generally, you can't add a neutral bar, and don't need to, because UL requires panels have enough neutral lugs.
You need to do a neutral ground smash. I consider it a 2-step process.
First, look closely at your panel labeling to see what it says about multiple ground wires per neutral lug.  Some allow 2, some allow 3. Do not mix metals on the same lug.  Pack the ground wires to the greatest extent allowed.
Second, if that doesn't work, or if it's obvious it won't work, or if you just like panache... look closely again at your panel labeling to see which models of accessory ground bar it recommends. Those will fit pre-drilled sites in the back of the panel, and several sites exist, and populate as many as you like. They may be under many wires, so look around and watch out for the always-energized input lugs.  Then, move grounds to the accessory ground bar(s).
Note the "how many grounds per lug" number on an accessory ground bar may be different than on a neutral bar. This will be on the panel labeling.
